# Deploying using AWS CI/CI process for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-code-deploy

Currently I can deploy my Ruby on Rails app to a pre-configured ec2 instance using Capistrano `cap production deploy`.

I'm trying to use CodeCommit, CodeBuild, CodeDeploy and CodePipeline.

[image: CodePipeline Setup]

I'm thinking of adding a CodeDeploy after the build passed from CodeBuild.

How can I use CodeDeploy to run a script like `cap production deploy` and deploy to my instance?

Comment: did you ever get this working? I'm currently trying to get cap production deploy to work but, my ubuntu ec2 instance keeps failing to connect via ssh

Answer (score 2):

CodeDeploy allows script execution using lifecycle hook: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html. You can add a script that execute the command and specify the script in the ApplicationStart section of your appspec file.